# SQL Server: CTE tree with priority

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have some troubles how to build a query for a recursive parent-child tree in SQL Server.

I have found some common table expression but i have to consider another parameter (the priority in each level) that i have not found from a search over the internet, so the structure of my table is like this

```
id - parentid - proprity
```

For example if i have this data:

```
1 - NULL - 2
2 - NULL - 1
3 - 2 - 2
4 - 3 - 1
5 - 2 - 0
6 - 1 - 0
7 - 2 - 3
```

The query must return this at right order:

```
-2
--5
--3
---4
--7
-1
--6
```

Also this list is orderable so if any order is change I have to reset the priority at right place. Anyone has already a solution for this case with queries in SQL Server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Just involve the priority in the ORDER BY.    Post your query, and we can debug it.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the order that you need. Personally, I'd try to do that ordering in the display layer, but this will do it in SQL.

This relies on single-digit priority values. If those might be larger then you'll need to prepend leading 0s to the priorities, like: `RIGHT('0' + priority, 2)`.

The query just builds a string of the priorities at each point so that you can then order off of it.

```
;WITH Hierarchy_CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        id,
        parent_id,
        CAST([priority] AS VARCHAR(100)) AS priority_string,
        id AS base,
        1 AS lvl
    FROM
        My_Table
    WHERE
        parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        MT.id,
        MT.parent_id,
        CAST(H.priority_string + CAST(MT.priority AS VARCHAR(20)) AS VARCHAR(100)),
        H.base,
        H.lvl + 1
    FROM
        Hierarchy_CTE H
    INNER JOIN My_Table MT ON MT.parent_id = H.id
)
SELECT
    id,
    base,
    lvl
FROM
    Hierarchy_CTE
ORDER BY
    priority_string
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, i've tried your query but it doesn't work properly if you have more than 10 items, because the first level items after tenth "relative" position are upper than they must.

Comment: I just ran the query with 11 items and it returned results exactly as expected. Do you mean a priority of greater than 10? As I explained in my answer, you must change the code if that is the case. If you're still having trouble then please add additional sample data and expected output to your question that causes this to fail and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I've tried with at least four level with random priorities... A solution could be add padding zeros with a total fixed length... ASAP i will try this solution and i noticed you the result

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this solution is working (taken from Tom H answer):

```
;WITH Hierarchy_CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        id,
        parent_id,
        CAST(REPLICATE('0', 10 - LEN(CAST([Order] AS VARCHAR))) + CAST([Order] AS VARCHAR) + '.' + 
    REPLICATE('0', 10 - LEN(CAST(MerchantCategoryId AS VARCHAR))) + CAST(MerchantCategoryId AS VARCHAR) AS VARCHAR(4000)) AS priority_string,
        id AS base,
        1 AS lvl
    FROM
        My_Table
    WHERE
        parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        MT.id,
        MT.parent_id,
        CAST(H.priority_string + '|' + REPLICATE('0', 10 - LEN(CAST(MT.[priority] AS VARCHAR))) + CAST(MT.[priority] AS VARCHAR) + '.' + 
    REPLICATE('0', 10 - LEN(CAST(MT.id AS VARCHAR))) + CAST(MT.id AS VARCHAR) AS VARCHAR(4000)) AS priority_string,
        H.base,
        H.lvl + 1
    FROM
        Hierarchy_CTE H
    INNER JOIN My_Table MT ON MT.parent_id = H.id
)
SELECT
    id,
    base,
    lvl
FROM
    Hierarchy_CTE
ORDER BY
    priority_string
```

I added padding zeros equal to a fixed length minus then "stringified" priority length and also for the id, so i can order them to the priority and then for id.
This solution works only in ascending orders (not work for descending orders with the maintenance of a tree view), but this list is useful for me only when i have to save updated priorities, so it may be enough.